# Update multiple ids against single id (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update multiple `Departments` against one unit. I tried this method, but it's not correct.

How can I update multiple departments ids?

Form:

[image]

Request:

[image]

Controller Function:

```
$pre_data = UnitDepartment::where('unit_id', $request->id)->get();
    if ($pre_data) {
        foreach ($pre_data as $value) {
            $value->delete();
        }
        $department = $request->department_id;
        foreach ($department as $value) {
            $unitDepart = new UnitDepartment();
            $unitDepart->unit_id = $request->id;
            $unitDepart->department_id = $value;
            $unitDepart->save();
        }
    }
```

table:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that is the table related to departments and units.

So you can build the relationship [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between them,

Create the relationship in your models,

In Unit model:

```php
    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Unit','unit_department','unit_id','department_id');
    }
```

In Department Model:

```php
    public function units()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Department','unit_department','department_id','unit_id');
    }
```

Attach the new relationship, simply use:

```php
Unit::find($request->unit_id)->departments()
                             ->sync($request->department_id);
```

---

Unfortunately, you cannot use **softDelete** on `sync()`.

And I don't think you need to soft delete with `unit_departments`. As a `pivot` then it should be irrelevant if it is deleted or not.

And if user update the relationship on the frequent, this table will grow fast.

If you really need to soft-delete, you can write it like this:

```php
$department_ids = $request->department_id;
$unit_id = $request->unit_id

// soft delete the unit_departments not in request:
UnitDepartment::where('unit_id', $unit_id)->whereNotIn('department_id', $department_ids)->delete();

// insert the new department_id+unit_id relationship
$exist_department_ids = UnitDepartment::where('unit_id', $unit_id)->whereIn('department_id', $department_ids)->pluck('department_ids')->all();

$dept_ids = array_diff($exist_department_ids, $department_ids);
$depts = collect($dept_ids)->map(function($dept_id) use ($unit_id) { 
    return ['department_id' => $dept_id, 'unit_id' => $unit_id];
});
UnitDepartment::insert($depts);
```

Comment: there is two ids save already that will be updated but what about the new department_id?

Comment: i don't want to delete them which are already exist. i just want to add new ids.

Comment: @FahadArs However, you deleted them your post?

Comment: i just want to check ids which are not exist in table. and just add them.

Comment: @FahadArs query in foreach will slow the performance. Try my new code.

Comment: @FahadArs use migration to add the unique, However, I found that the table is the relationship table. I think you can easily use `syncWithoutDetaching` to insert the datas.

Comment: @TsailKoga i tried that one i just posted. but there is also problem. if user unchecked any of field.

Comment: @FahadArs so you still want to delete them, then just use `->sync($datas)` it will update or delete or insert automatically according to the `$datas`

Comment: thanks it works. can i just softDelete data which is deleted by sync()

Comment: @FahadArs Unfortunately,  cannot use softDelete on `sync()`. And I don't think you need to soft delete with `unit_departments`. As a pivot then it should be irrelevant if it is deleted or not.

Comment: but i want it to be soft deleted

Comment: @FahadArs If you really want to use soft-delete, I have updated the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you're sending `unit_id` in the request, however using `$request->id` in the query which is wrong.
Change every occurance of `$request->id` with `$request->unit_id` in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

to select pre data correctly 
use

```
$pre_data = UnitDepartment::where('unit_id', $request->id)->first();
```

Comment: `get()` get data in array and you won't be able to loop in `foreach()`

Comment: because i  fetch multiple ids not one.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this

```
$unit = UnitDepartment::where('unit_id', $request->unit_id)->get();
    foreach ($unit as $item) {
        $existDepartment[] = $item->department_id;
    }
    $newDepartment = $request->department_id;
    $result = array_diff($newDepartment, $existDepartment);
    if ($result) {
        foreach ($result as $item) {
            $data = new UnitDepartment();
            $data->unit_id = $request->unit_id;
            $data->department_id = $item;
            $data->save();
        }
    }
```